# what happens after I dispose an object?

Tags: c#, dispose

I have a `Label` on my `Form`. when I call `Dispose()` method ,object removes from `Form`. But still I can set its properties. What happens after I call `Dispose()` Method for an object. can I recover it and show it again?

```
public void MyMethod()
{
     label1.Dispose();
     label1.Text = "Test";
     //No error happens
}
```

after disposing I can read some properties like Left property. It means label still exist in somewhere. How I can completely remove it?

Comment: When you call the object's `Dispose` method, the object's `Dispose` method gets executed. It's just a regular old method that in most cases is implementing `IDisposable.Dispose`. The only special thing about the method is that it gets invoked automatically if you use the object in `using` block.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What happens in this case, is that the control's handle is destroyed (and thus removed from its parent). After disposing, it can no longer be added to a visible display. However, the object itself, as in the class instance, still exists, and thus most properties can be set. (some will give an objectdisposed exception, such as trying to obtain the Handle property)

In general, which properties can still be set, depends on an object's implementation (of the IDispose interface), and where it checks if it is disposed.

Comment: one more thing to add. It has nothing to do with UI. It is the General "Dispose" pattern.

Comment: after disposing I can read some properties like Left property. It means label steel exist in somewhere. How I can completely remove it?

Comment: For an object to be released from memory, it has to be available for Garbage Collection. For that to happen, first thing is that all references to it must be gone. So here step 1 would be, after disposing, to set: label1 = null;  Disposing is a separate step, because that immediately frees the handle. After the reference is destroyed, the object instance itself, is available for garbarge collection. If you want to force immediate garbage collection, you can call GC.Collect(), but normally the system will do that for you.

Answer (score -2):

`obj.Dispose()` commands GC to destroy that object. If You try to change its data after `obj.Dispose()` nothing will happen.

Comment: This isn't true. IDisposable is an arbitrary disposal.